# ie issue. nested relative DIV's not moving with scroll

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, css

I have a great layout and some jquery effects that works in FF, Safari, Chrome and ie9. Everything works in ie8 with the exception being the scroll. I have removed the jquery and reproduced the issue with HTML and XML using Transitional doctype.

When I scroll in ie8, using the example in the link below, the only thing that scrolls is the "Spacer" text. everything else stays fixed and spills out of the wrapping div. The wrapping div in my layout uses overflow:hidden but the problem exists with or without overflow. I have omitted overflow for easier testing of the issue.

I have tested in ie9 using compatibility view and also ie8 installed on a test pc.

Please see my jsfiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/chrisrth/6ZNMB/1/

Comment: Can I suggest you modify your code to use semantic CSS classes instead of using inline styles. It would also be quite helpful to see the code in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). [As an example I've pasted the current code.](http://jsfiddle.net/kywjA/)

Comment: Thanks. I need to slow down when asking questions. I use stylesheets but omitted them to quickly post my question. All cleaned up. Link posted above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

making the parent or top level DIV `position:absolute` fixed the scrolling and overflow issues with ie8 and caused no change on mozilla and ie9

Comment: wow after 6 hours of going Crazy trying to work out what my scrolling problem was in ie8 this did the trick - Thank you!!